# set a event listener collision for all image in a list.

Tags: list, lua, collision-detection, coronasdk, addeventlistener

i have a section that randomly spawns images from a one list and spawns them on screen and despawns them continously. the images that are spawned are put into a list called object. i trying to make is so that each image that is spawned on screen has a collision detection by the user sprite. however at the moment it only detects the very first raft that is spawned.

```
isOnRaft = 0

--Set log position and movement
local mRandom = math.random
local raft = {"Raft1" ,"Raft2"}
local objectTag = 0
local object = {}

function spawnlogright()
    objectTag = objectTag + 1
    local objIdx = mRandom(#raft)
    local objName = raft[objIdx]
    object[objectTag]  = display.newImage(objName..".png")
    object[objectTag].x = 416
    object[objectTag].y = 72
    object[objectTag].name = objectTag
    transition.to(object[objectTag], {time = 10000, x = -96, onComplete = function(obj) obj:removeSelf(); obj = nil; end})
    physics.addBody( object[objectTag], "static", {isSensor = true})
end
spawnlogright()
timer.performWithDelay(3500,spawnlogright,0)

function spawnlogright()
    objectTag = objectTag + 1
    local objIdx = mRandom(#raft)
    local objName = raft[objIdx]
    object[objectTag]  = display.newImage(objName..".png")
    object[objectTag].x = 416
    object[objectTag].y = 168
    object[objectTag].name = objectTag
    transition.to(object[objectTag], {time = 10000, x = -96, onComplete = function(obj) obj:removeSelf(); obj = nil; end})
    physics.addBody( object[objectTag], "static", {isSensor = true})
end
spawnlogright()
timer.performWithDelay(3500,spawnlogright,0)

function spawnlogleft()
    objectTag = objectTag + 1
    local objIdx = mRandom(#raft)
    local objName = raft[objIdx]
    object[objectTag]  = display.newImage(objName..".png")
    object[objectTag].x = -96
    object[objectTag].y = 120
    object[objectTag].name = objectTag
    transition.to(object[objectTag], {time = 10000, x = 416, onComplete = function(obj) obj:removeSelf(); obj = nil; end})
    physics.addBody( object[objectTag], "static", {isSensor = true})
end
spawnlogleft()
timer.performWithDelay(3500,spawnlogleft,0)

function spawnlogleft()
    objectTag = objectTag + 1
    local objIdx = mRandom(#raft)
    local objName = raft[objIdx]
    object[objectTag]  = display.newImage(objName..".png")
    object[objectTag].x = -96
    object[objectTag].y = 216
    object[objectTag].name = objectTag
    transition.to(object[objectTag], {time = 10000, x = 416, onComplete = function(obj) obj:removeSelf(); obj = nil; end})
    physics.addBody( object[objectTag], "static", {isSensor = true})    
end
spawnlogleft()
timer.performWithDelay(3500,spawnlogleft,0)

--while the frog is on the log...
function raftCollide(event)
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
         isOnRaft = isOnRaft + 1
        print(isOnLog)
    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" )then
        isOnRaft = isOnRaft - 1
        print(isOnLog)
    end
end

--add event for 'walking on the log'
object[objectTag]:addEventListener("collision", raftCollide)
```

so i need the user sprite to detect all of the rafts that are spawned and add 1 to isOnRaft. this will negate the water death function. is there a way to add the collision detection to all of the raft or all of the entities within the object list.

any help would be appriacaited thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the last line by:

```
for logTag, logObject in pairs(object) do
    logObject:addEventListener("collision", raftCollide)
end
```

Also just an advice but do what you feel like with it: Try not to declare 2 functions with the same names in the same scope... You should change the name of the second spawnRight / spawnLeft functions to have a different name :)